# subsetting matrix while preserving row.names

Tags: r, matrix, performance

I'm trying to subset a matrix so that I only get the matrix where the first variable is larger than the second variable. I have the matrix `out` which is a `3000x2` matrix.

I tried

```
out<-out[out[,1] > out[,2]]
```

but this eliminates the row.names altogether, and I get a string of integers between 1 to 3000. Would there be a way to preserve the `row.names`?

Comment: All you need is a comma. `out[out[,1] > out[,2] , ]`

Comment: @NealFultz: you should post that as an answer... maybe explaining why you need a comma ;)

Answer (score 5):

Of note, if you only return a subset of one row to form a matrix with one dimension being unity, R will drop the row name:

`m <- matrix(1:9, ncol = 3)
rownames(m) <- c("a", "b", "c")
m[1, ] # lost the row name
m[1, , drop = FALSE] # got row name back and a matrix
m[c(1,1), ] # the row name is back when result has nrow > 1`

There appears to be no simple way of working around this other than checking for one-row result and assigning the row name.

Comment: the best one ever for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

A matrix is treated by R as a vector with columns and rows.

```
> A <- matrix(1:9, ncol=3)

# A is filled with 1,...,9 columnwise
> A
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    2    5    8
[3,]    3    6    9

# only elements with even number in 2nd column of same row

> v <- A[A[,2] %% 2 == 0]

> m <- A[A[,2] %% 2 == 0,]

> v
[1] 1 3 4 6 7 9

> m
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    3    6    9

# The result of evaluating odd/even-ness of middle column.
# This boolean vector is repeated column-wise by default
# until all element's fate in A is determined.

> A[,2] %% 2 == 0
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

When you leave out the comma (`v`), then you address `A` as a 1-dimensional data structure and R implicitely handles your expression as a vector.

v is in that sense not "string of integers" but a vector of integers. When you add the comma, then you tell R that your condition only adresses the first dimension while indicating a second one (after the comma) - which causes R to handle your expression as a matrix (`m`).